# How to write a test case for a setInterval() function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a timer and assume a specific function will be executed when the counter is counting to 3.

```js
var a_interval_function = function(){
    var counter = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(counter === 5){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        // run the function when the counter is 3
        if(counter === 3){
            a_function_should_be_runned();
        }   

        counter++;
    }, 500);

    return interval;
}
```

However, I don't know how to establish a valid test case for testing the counter as well as the timing when the function is executed. Does anyone know how to do it? Something like the following:

```js
// and some test case like this
it('a timer test', function(done){
    var interval = a_interval_function();
    expect(a_function_should_be_runned.state).to.equal({
        name: 'runned',
        counter: 3,
        time: 300,
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`sinon.useFakeTimers()`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock).

For example:

```
var sinon  = require('sinon');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var a_function_should_be_runned = sinon.spy();

var a_interval_function = function(){
  var counter = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(counter === 5){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    // run the function when the counter is 3
    if(counter === 3){
      a_function_should_be_runned();
    }   

    counter++;
  }, 500);

  return interval;
}

describe('timer tests', function() {

  before(function() {
    this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });

  after(function() {
    this.clock.restore();
  });

  it('a timer test', function() {
    var interval = a_interval_function();

    // At time 0, we don't expect the function to have been called.
    expect(a_function_should_be_runned.called).to.be.false;

    // Advance clock 500ms.
    this.clock.tick(500);
    expect(a_function_should_be_runned.called).to.be.false;

    // Advance clock again (1s since start)
    this.clock.tick(500);
    expect(a_function_should_be_runned.called).to.be.false;

    // Advance clock again (1.5s since start). This should
    // trigger the call to `a_function_should_be_runned`.
    this.clock.tick(500);
    expect(a_function_should_be_runned.called).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need!.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my naïve approach:

```
it('a timer test', function(done){
    var interval = a_interval_function();
    setTimeout(function () {
        expect(a_function_should_be_runned.state).to.equal({
            name: 'runned',
            counter: 3,
            time: 300,
        });
        done();
    }, 3.5 * 500);
});
```

What you do here is basically waiting 1.75s and expecting that the `a_function_should_be_runned` function has been executed on timeout. Then you call the `expect` function in order to check your assertion. Finally you call `done()`. Note that `done()` is called inside the `setTimeout` callback function. If you don't call `done()` your test just times out.

Comment: Calling the done function just telling mocha the aync test case is done.

Comment: @TonyHsieh Yes, because at this point it is really done. What you do here is basically waiting 1.75s and expecting that the `a_function_should_be_runned` has been executed on timeout. Then you call the `expect` function in order to check your assertion. And finally you call `done()`. Note that `done()` is called inside the `setTimeout` callback function. If you don't call `done()` your test just times out.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the I want to make sure the function is exected in the right time.

Comment: @TonyHsieh If you must be exact you should try robertklep’s approach  and use [sinon.useFakeTimers()](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock)  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34310556/601466).

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way to check if the code / function gets executed is just by putting in an alert or `console.log`, so you have visual confirmation of what is happening. Also you can `console.log` the counter in your interval so you can see the counter going up.

grammar nazies in the house....

[edit]

```
var a_interval_function = function(){
    var counter = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(counter === 5){
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        // run the function when the counter is 3
        if(counter === 3 && testFunction()){
            a_function_should_be_runned();
        }   

        counter++;
    }, 500);

    return interval;
}

function testFunction(){
     if(KeyboardNinja == 'awesome'){
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }


}
```

Your test will never fail :P

Comment: You didnt tell that :P . Havn't you got some sort of development enviourment. Your own browser maybe?

Comment: Yes, the function will run in browser environment, But I want to write a test case which makes this to run automatioin.

Comment: AFAIK: You will  have to mock the setInterval.

Comment: Aah right...Than you with have to add some callback functions with data you expect to come through and check if those are correct

Comment: I tred callback functions, If the callback function not executed, then the test case still passed, that's not right

Comment: At this moment you are just checking "if counter == 3" but should also check if the test has passed. ill make some code for you :)